# Infinite Loop in Babel with Rotating Sidewaystable

Tags: tables, babel, rotating

I don't know whether this is a babel or a rotating bug, and I have filed a report with Debian (http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=710031), but perhaps someone knows a workaround. The following code results in an infinite loop:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}

\tracingall

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]\footnotesize
\centering{
\caption{\textbf{babel and sidewaystable}}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l l}
Hello &   World \\
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

If you turn "sidewaystable" into "table" it works just fine. I encountered one other error with babel after upgrading recently, namely an infinite loop with nicefrac. Any insight, advice?

Running with `\listfiles` I get the following.

```
**File List:**
book.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
bk12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
english.ldf    2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
rotating.sty    2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Comment: Can't confirm this happens. (Final version of TeXLive2012:  pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012), rotating.sty 2009/03/28 v2.16a,  babel.sty 2008/07/08 v3.8m)

Comment: Good point: here are my versions, which are different:

    `texlive-base 2013.20130523-1`
    `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14`
    `rotating.sty 2009/03/28 v2.16a`
    `babel 2013/05/16 v3.9f`

Comment: I also have no problems (but with the same versions as @UlrichSchwarz).  What happens when you comment out `babel`?

Comment: Of course, there is no infinite loop if I comment out babel. But I am making a multilanguage document (greek and english), so I need babel.

Comment: No infinite loop here on TeX Live 2013/pretest, same date stamps and versions as yours. Can you add the output you get by adding `\listfiles`?

Comment: egreg: I have added the output of \listfiles.

Comment: How is there no `babel`-related lines from your `\listfiles` output..?  There should be at least two --- `babel.sty` and `english.ldf` --- located above the `rotating.sty` line.

Comment: jon: Well, I don't know.

Comment: I had commented out the babel line. If I include it, of course, the \listfiles shows it. I have amended the output.

Comment: You mentioned `babel 3.9f` but the listing shows `babel 3.8m`

Comment: BTW (not related to the question): `\centering` does not take an argument, thus the curly braces do not serve a purpose here. If you want to use bold caption texts, then consider package `caption`, that has many options to change the style of the captions.

Comment: egreg: You are right. I don't know how that happened, considering that I don't have any manually installed tex packages, but I will bring that one up to date and try again.

Comment: Removing and purging all texlive packages, then deleting all tex-related folders and files remaining, then reinstalling texlive-full allowed me to use sideways table and babel together. Somehow, the babel package was not updated during the installation of Debian's texlive 2013, and that old version, babel 3.8m, caused the infinite loop. Thank you all for helping me debug this, especially you egreg.